# Indexing and search in a text file

Tags: python, text, indexing, full-text-search

I have a text file that contains the contents of a book. I want to take this file and build an index which allows the user to search through the file to make searches.

The search would consist of entering a word. Then, the program would return the following:

- Every chapter which includes that word.
- The line number of the line
  which contains the word.
- The entire line the word is on.

I tried the following code:

```
infile =   open(file)

Dict = {}

word = input("Enter a word to search: ")

linenum = 0
line = infile.readline()
for line in infile
    linenum += 1
    for word in wordList:
        if word in line:
            Dict[word] = Dict.setdefault(word, []) + [linenum]
            print(count, word)
    line = infile.readline()

return Dict
```

Something like this does not work and seems too awkward for handling the other modules which would require:

- An "or" operator to search for one word or another
- An "and" operator to search for one word and another in the same chapter

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Is this homework? Search is hard. Use an existing solution like ElasticSearch.

Comment: I used to work in document management systems, which do the same thing as you're doing for one book to entire libraries, and confirm the comment from @AssafLavie that text indexing is difficult to do well.  The process of cutting the text up into words is far more difficult than it first appears, particularly since some words are actually phrases (is "1st Feb 2016" one word or three words?  Is "...apple and/or orange..." three words or four?).  Use a pre-built text indexing library.

Comment: How about making this a working example? You do things like use variables that don't exist and try to `return` when you aren't in a function. This makes an answer more difficult.

Comment: If you could upload a sample of the input text file, maybe I'll write the code for you.

Comment: the input is merely just a .txt file of a book which is supposed to work for all books of the same format. all I want to accomplish is to allow the user to search the book to find a word, or series of words, then print every chapter title the word occurs in and every  line which contains said word. this build is giving me trouble syntactically or maybe logically

Comment: its simpler using a built in but id ideally like to build it

Comment: any thoughts ? or guidance or anything would be appreciated @AnmolSinghJaggi

Comment: How are the chapters arranged in the text? Is there any marking where a chapter begins/ends?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi every chapter has the pattern in these txt files that each chapter title will always be in all capitalized letters

Comment: So, does it look like [this](http://pastebin.com/sTLJQ7Bq)?

Comment: thanks! yes sorry, chapter starts with a blank line, then title in all capitalization, then a blank line it appears to be the pattern in the files. so essentially what you have

Comment: perhaps a dict of dict of dict? I have been trying and nothing seems to work @AnmolSinghJaggi

Comment: @newtTongue I'll upload the code in some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def classify_lines_on_chapter(book_contents):
    lines_vs_chapter = []
    for line in book_contents:
        if line.isupper():
            current_chapter = line.strip()
        lines_vs_chapter.append(current_chapter)
    return lines_vs_chapter


def classify_words_on_lines(book_contents):
    words_vs_lines = {}
    for i, line in enumerate(book_contents):
        for word in set([word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in line.split()]):
            if word:
                words_vs_lines.setdefault(word, []).append(i)
    return words_vs_lines


def main():
    skip_lines = 93

    with open('book.txt') as book:
        book_contents = book.readlines()[skip_lines:]

    lines_vs_chapter = classify_lines_on_chapter(book_contents)
    words_vs_lines = classify_words_on_lines(book_contents)

    while True:
        word = input("Enter word to search - ")
        # Enter a blank input to exit
        if not word:
            break

        line_numbers = words_vs_lines.get(word, None)
        if not line_numbers:
            print("Word not found!!\n")
            continue

        for line_number in line_numbers:
            line = book_contents[line_number]
            chapter = lines_vs_chapter[line_number]
            print("Line " + str(line_number + 1 + skip_lines))
            print("Chapter '" + str(chapter) + "'")
            print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Try it on [this input file](http://pastebin.com/66XBzWWp). Rename it as `book.txt` before running it.

Comment: thanks for your time! this is a nice streamlined build which is actually pretty similar to my attempt. just a few notes: it may be my input file, but its encountering an index out of bounds error at     'chapter = lines_vs_chapter[line_number]'   2) say the user enters _n_ words is there a functionality to handle that? or the and / or operands I mentioned in the original post

Comment: Can you upload your input file so that I can debug it. Also, I don't understand what you mean by 'n words'?

Comment: by _n_ i just mean if the user wanted to search for multiple words in the same search. so user input = (word _space_ word2 _space_ word3,...) and it search and return only the chapters  that contain all of those words with the lines they occur on. so it would return the chapter title, then the first word, the line number and line of the first word. then print the second word, the line number and line of that word and so on. the and / or would function like a search engine operator: takes 2 words, shows chapters and line with both words, or shows the chapter and line with either (or) two inputs

Comment: also, here's an example of the catalog [book](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/514/pg514.txt)

Comment: Ok. I think that's easily possible after a little modification of the code.

Comment: I have been trying to handle this index out of bounds error and its been nothing but trouble. it works in about half the queries but cant seem to make it past line_num 500 or so in the debugger... did you get a chance to take a  look?

Comment: @newtTongue It seems to be working fine on my system. Is there any specific input on which it is showing that error?

Comment: if you try it in the file i posted above it hits an index out of bounds error as the list index is out of range (i tried "tree" and "women" [here is the error file](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/514/pg514.txt) also can you take a look at the multiple word handling and operators if you could. this index range is really a pest

Comment: It's working fine on my system. (Note that I've deleted the first 95 lines from the input file. The first line now is 'CHAPTER ONE'. )

Comment: Also, I've fixed an unrelated bug. Check the new code!

Comment: [Output for `women`](http://pastebin.com/jJV1TAsn).  [Output for `tree`](http://pastebin.com/JgyVgjiq).

Comment: okay this is good stuff! error throw seems gone in all instances.  two things how do I handle this without removing the first 95 or whatever lines? and how do I approach multiple word query handling like in the original post? thanks for your help my friend, its been tremendous!

Comment: But, the first chapter starts at line 95. What will I output as `chapter` for a word in the first 95 lines ?

Comment: effectively, im just looking to leave the lines in there, yet just skip them as if they do not exist and start at chapter one like we do in your code. something like [94:]

Comment: exactly what I was going for! very nice

Comment: let me know if you get a chance to take a look at those other tasks if you are able to. also,  i think the indexing bounds throw has been completely debugged for all inputs so that is great progress.

Comment: @newtTongue I'm glad that it's error-free now! And as far as those other tasks are concerned, I'm afraid that they are beyond my capability. Extremely sorry for that! :(